# Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am android c# developer beginner and need to work in back ground showing my listview but my code have a load action such as fetching database and convert from byte array to image so I used async task but it hangs and give me this error Unhandled Exception:

Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException:  occurred

```
//this my async class :

public class UpdatePB : AsyncTask<string, string, string>
{
    private Activity context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public List<Advertise_TableItem> GroupLst;
    Dictionary<Advertise_TableItem, List<Replies_TableItem>> ChildLst;
    //  Advertise_HomeScreenAdapter adb;
    public ExpandableListViewAdapter Adapter;
    AbdoService.abdo_service AbdoService;

    //string user_id;
    Context myContext;
    ExpandableListView listview;
    DataTable table;
    public UpdatePB(Activity context, ExpandableListView listview, Context myContext)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listview = listview;
        this.myContext = myContext;


    }
    protected override string RunInBackground(string[] @params)
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

        //adb = new Advertise_HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);
        //listview.Adapter = adb;

        //progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        //progressDialog.Show();


        AbdoService = new AbdoService.abdo_service();

        GroupLst = new List<Advertise_TableItem>();
        ChildLst = new Dictionary<Advertise_TableItem, List<Replies_TableItem>>();
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {


            table = AbdoService.selectAllAdvertises().table;

            int I = 0;
            foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
            {
                // bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(AbdoService.GetByteImage(item[1].ToString()).ByteImage, 0, AbdoService.GetByteImage(item[1].ToString()).ByteImage.Length);


                GroupLst.Add(new Advertise_TableItem(item[1].ToString(), item[2].ToString(), item[3].ToString(), item[0].ToString()));
                List<Replies_TableItem> child = new List<Replies_TableItem>();
                //child.Add(new Replies_TableItem("mohammed", "comment 1 "));
                //child.Add(new Replies_TableItem("ahmed", "comment 2 "));
                var childTable = AbdoService.selectReply(item[0].ToString());
                foreach (DataRow childItem in childTable.table.Rows)
                {
                    child.Add(new Replies_TableItem(childItem[1].ToString(), childItem[2].ToString()));
                }
                ChildLst.Add(GroupLst[I], child);

                I++;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            if_connected();
        }



        Adapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(myContext, GroupLst, ChildLst);
        ////System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        listview.SetAdapter(Adapter);


        for (int i = 0; i < Adapter.GroupCount; i++)
        {
            listview.ExpandGroup(i);
        }

        //listview.GroupClick += Listview_GroupClick;

        //startServices();
        ////RunOnUiThread(() => progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible);

        return context.Title;

    }
    public void if_connected()
    {





        var callDialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        callDialog.SetTitle("Notify");
        callDialog.SetMessage("connect internet");
        callDialog.SetNeutralButton("ok", delegate
        {
            context.Finish();
            context.StartActivity(typeof(AllAdvertises));
        });
        callDialog.Show();

    }
    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.Show();

    }

    //protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params string[] values)
    //{
    //    //mtv.Text = Convert.ToString(values[0]);
    //    //Android.Util.Log.Error("lv==", values[0] + "");
    //    listview.SetAdapter(Adapter);


    //    for (int i = 0; i < Adapter.GroupCount; i++)
    //    {
    //        listview.ExpandGroup(i);
    //    }

    //}
    protected override void OnPostExecute(string result)
    {
        result = context.Title;

        progressDialog.Dismiss();
    }


}
//this is my Activity function oncreate()
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AllAdvertises);

        //progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        //progressDialog.SetMessage("hiiiiiiiiiiiii");
        //progressDialog.Show();
        //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);



        //ProgressBar progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);

        //RunOnUiThread(() => progressBar.Visibility=ViewStates.Visible);
        //DoSomeWork1(arguments);




        prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        TextView UserName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtUserName);
        string user_id = prefs.GetString("UserId", "0");
        if (user_id != "0")
        {
            UserName.Text = " Hello " + prefs.GetString("UserName", "0");
        }


        //AbdoService = new AbdoService.abdo_service();

        ////table= b.GetResult();
        ////    //AbdoService.selectAllAdvertisesCompleted += AbdoService_selectAllAdvertisesCompleted;
        ////    //AbdoService.selectAllAdvertisesAsync();
        listview = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.EdListView);
        //GroupLst = new List<Advertise_TableItem>();
        //ChildLst = new Dictionary<Advertise_TableItem, List<Replies_TableItem>>();
        //if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        //{


        //    //table = AbdoService.selectAllAdvertises().table;

        //    int I = 0;
        //    foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
        //    {
        //        // bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(AbdoService.GetByteImage(item[1].ToString()).ByteImage, 0, AbdoService.GetByteImage(item[1].ToString()).ByteImage.Length);


        //        GroupLst.Add(new Advertise_TableItem(item[1].ToString(), item[2].ToString(), item[3].ToString(), item[0].ToString()));
        //        List<Replies_TableItem> child = new List<Replies_TableItem>();
        //        //child.Add(new Replies_TableItem("mohammed", "comment 1 "));
        //        //child.Add(new Replies_TableItem("ahmed", "comment 2 "));
        //        var childTable = AbdoService.selectReply(item[0].ToString());
        //        foreach (DataRow childItem in childTable.table.Rows)
        //        {
        //            child.Add(new Replies_TableItem(childItem[1].ToString(), childItem[2].ToString()));
        //        }
        //        ChildLst.Add(GroupLst[I], child);

        //        I++;

        //    }
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    if_connected();
        //}
        ////adb = new Advertise_HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);
        ////listview.Adapter = adb;






        //Adapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, GroupLst, ChildLst);
        UpdatePB uptask = new UpdatePB(this, listview, this);
        uptask.Execute("paramter");
        //uptask.GetResult();
        //listview.SetAdapter(Adapter);
        //for (int i = 0; i < Adapter.GroupCount; i++)
        //{
        //    listview.ExpandGroup(i);
        //}

        listview.GroupClick += Listview_GroupClick;

        startServices();

        //////RunOnUiThread(() => progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not touch the UI from a background thread so you need to move this line:

```
listview.SetAdapter(Adapter);
for (int i = 0; i < Adapter.GroupCount; i++)
 {
      listview.ExpandGroup(i);
 }
```

from `RunInBackground(string[] @params)` to `OnPostExecute(string result)`

also move `if_connected();` from `RunInBackground(string[] @params)` to `OnPostExecute(string result)` because `if_connected();` shows a dialog it can not be run in background

And add your complete Stack Trace of error to your question because there may be some other errors there in addition to mentioned ones.

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly but why that shows some thing must remove it from RunInBackground(string[] @params)

Comment: what about using uptask.GetResult(); to retrieve some variables from class uptask but when use uptask.GetResult(); the dialogue progress not showing why ?

Comment: @mohamedsayed when you are in background you have no access to UI (you can not touch UI) and you can not show any UI (dialog or any other UI) to user.

Comment: but if ui is the heavy process what should i do

Comment: @mohamedsayed what you mean about "heavy"? in UI you can not do heavy things (such as File, DB or NET I/O ) if you do the user can not interact with the UI and your app seems to freeze and no one wants the UI to freeze and do not response

Comment: but when show list view i  download  a pic that considered a heavy process that is implement in listview adapter and can not implement it in back ground as you saw

Comment: @mohamedsayed it is a common job to download a pic in background thread and show it in UI thread after downloading. you can send any object from `RunInBackground` to `OnPostExecute`. but i offer you to use `Glide` or `Picasso` library to do your job because they have a clear API: `glide:`  https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html  `picaso:`   https://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @mohamedsayed you do not touch the UI from background thread but you can send the result to the UI Thread and the UI thread can change the UI

Comment: @mohamedsayed when using `Glide` or `Picasso` you do not need to use a background thread the library do it for you so working with them is simpler